# Can't pass through data to second controller with segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I can't get a simple segue to work when a cell in a tableview gets pressed. It does go to the next view after I tapped two different items. But I can't pass any values from the first controller to the second. If I set a value to the label in the second controller and load it in the `viewDidLoad` method it shows up.

I'm going crazy as I've been trying to get this work for ages....

My storyboard: https://snag.gy/DCw9MU.jpg

CategoryListViewController(1st controller):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CategoryListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var categoryList = TestData.sharedInstance.categoryList


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.title = "iEngineer"
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.tableView .reloadData()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        for category in categoryList{
            print(category)
        }

    }

    // MARK: - Segues
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showFormulaList" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let category = self.categoryList[indexPath.row]
                let formulaListViewController = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! FormulaListViewController
                formulaListViewController.text = category
                formulaListViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
                formulaListViewController.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
            }
        }

    }

    // MARK: - Table View
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(categoryList.count)
        return categoryList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "categoryCell", for: indexPath)
        let object = categoryList[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = object
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showFormulaList", sender: self)
    }
}
```

FormulaListViewController(2nd controller):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class FormulaListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    var formulaList = TestData.sharedInstance.formulaList

    var fSwift: String!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.title = "iEngineer"
        print(fSwift)
        titleLabel.text = fSwift

    }

    // MARK: - Table View
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(formulaList.count)
        return formulaList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "formulaCell", for: indexPath)
        let object = formulaList[indexPath.row]
        print(object)
        cell.textLabel!.text = object
        return cell
    }
}
```

Where is my mistake or what am I doing wrong?

I greatly appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `didSelectRowAt` instead of `didDeselectRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showFormulaList", sender: self)
}
```

Also make sure segue source is the vc not the cell , and since you fire the segue in `didDeselectRowAt` this

```
if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
```

will be nil

Answer (score 0):

You have used `didDeselectRowAt`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showFormulaList", sender: self)
}
```

You need to use `didSelectRowAt`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "showFormulaList", sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showFormulaList", sender: self)
}
```

You should use didSelect instead of didDeselectRowAt, also you should pass something better than **self**, because with self you are passing the entire **CategoryListViewController** 
Try to pass the indexPath like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showFormulaList", sender: indexPath)
}
```

and change the function prepare in this

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showFormulaList" {
        if let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath {
            let category = self.categoryList[indexPath.row]
            let formulaListViewController = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! FormulaListViewController
            formulaListViewController.fuckSwift = category
            formulaListViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
            formulaListViewController.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }

}
```

If this doesn't help you try to debug your code and find where you lost your variable :)